# Troubles with Integrals, any good procedures for using integral tables?

Tags: integration

I have the following integral that I am trying to evaluate.

$$\int_0^{\Lambda}
\frac{dr}{\sqrt{-a \sqrt{a^2+4 r^2}+a^2+2 r^2}+
\sqrt{a \left(\sqrt{a^2+4 r^2}+a\right)+2 r^2}}$$

What I have tried so far is:

1) Brain dead try with *Mathematica*.

2) Break it up into partial fractions, and then proceed with mathematica with each one individually.

$$
 \frac{\sqrt{a^2+4 r^2} \sqrt{a \sqrt{a^2+4 r^2}+a^2+2 r^2}}{8 a r^2}
-\frac{a \sqrt{a \sqrt{a^2+4 r^2}+a^2+2 r^2}}{8 r^2 \sqrt{a^2+4 r^2}} \\
-\frac{\sqrt{a^2+4 r^2} \sqrt{-a \sqrt{a^2+4 r^2}+a^2+2 r^2}}{8 a r^2}
+\frac{a \sqrt{-a \sqrt{a^2+4 r^2}+a^2+2 r^2}}{8 r^2 \sqrt{a^2+4 r^2}}$$

3) With the partial fractions expansion, I have tried reducing the complexity of terms by pulling an $a^2$ out creating factors of $r'^2 = \dfrac{r^2}{a^2} \ldots$ and tried *Mathematica* again.

Similarly though this process I have been consulting integral tables. Specifically I have been using the book by Daiel Zwillinger... wow what a book!

> **My question**
>
> Does anyone have a good protocol for reducing integral forms to eventually find a corresponding form in the tables?

To a certain degree I imagine this is an art.

Also curious if anyone has helpful guidance for this task.

Comment: sweet juicy jesus!

Comment: where have you found this monster?

Comment: with some luck this can be reduced to an expression containing ellipitc integrals

Comment: @tired I found this through trying to evaluate an integral for a QED calculation. I had suspicion that it would end up elliptic, it was the elliptic integral section of Zwillinger that I was drawn to.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
  f(r) &=
  \frac{1}
       {\sqrt{a^2+2r^2+a\sqrt{a^2+4r^2}}+
        \sqrt{a^2+2r^2-a\sqrt{a^2+4r^2}}} \\ &=
  \frac{\sqrt{2}}
       {\sqrt{a^2+4r^2+2a\sqrt{a^2+4r^2}+a^2}+
        \sqrt{a^2+4r^2-2a\sqrt{a^2+4r^2}+a^2}} \\ &=
  \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{a^2+4 r^2}+a+\sqrt{a^2+4 r^2}-a} \\ &=
  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{a^2+4r^2}} \\
  \int_{0}^{\Lambda} f(r) \, dr &= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} \sinh^{-1} \frac{2\Lambda}{a}
\end{align*}